# InvalidResponseError: Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available

Tags: web3js, blockchain, javascript, nodejs, binance-smart-chain

I'm trying to interact with a smart contract on BSCtest using web3. I think the error occurs in this line

```
rs = await TokenContract.methods.transfer(receiverAddress, 100000).send({
    from: myAddress,
    gas: 3000000
  })
```

full code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const {Web3}  = require('web3');

myPrivateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const TokenAddress = "0x026e6631A3514e0B52c3D33c09D52Ab9574C2703";
const TokenAbi = [...]

myAddress = "0xb5253E9D3Ec90b7887Eec27a7F280D176Fd542A3";
receiverAddress = "0xF37ab5FC6D6093E281Be2129e10D5f86e2f20E11";

async function interact(){
  web3 = new Web3("https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s3.binance.org:8545");
  TokenContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(TokenAbi, TokenAddress);
  // myBalance = await TokenContract.methods.balanceOf(myAddress).call();
  // console.log(myBalance);

  await web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add({
    privateKey: myPrivateKey,
    address: myAddress
  });
  receiverBalanceBefore = await TokenContract.methods.balanceOf(receiverAddress).call();
  rs = await TokenContract.methods.transfer(receiverAddress, 100000).send({
    from: myAddress,
    gas: 3000000
  })

  receiverBalanceAfter = await TokenContract.methods.balanceOf(receiverAddress).call();
  console.log(receiverBalanceBefore, receiverBalanceAfter);
}
interact();
```

Does anyone help me with :(